# How do I install psycopg2 from jenkins pip requirements for Jenkins CI?

Tags: python, jenkins, continuous-integration

New to Jenkins, I'm trying to use my local Jenkins server to automate my tests as I make changes to my directory however, I'm getting the following error when I try to build the virtualenv so I can run tests against my codebase, it breaks at psycopg2 and I do not understand how I'm able to fix this. 
Is there a better approach to build my virtualenv and then test my code base?

```
Collecting psycopg2==2.6.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 32))
  Downloading psycopg2-2.6.1.tar.gz (371kB)
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info
    writing pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    Error: pg_config executable not found.

    Please add the directory containing pg_config to the PATH
    or specify the full executable path with the option:

        python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

    or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/l1/bwg91l0x1mn7dkjcw3bg569000007q/T/pip-build-TWCDOt/psycopg2
You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 8.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Build step 'Virtualenv Builder' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

The following is a pic of what my configuration is to help me setup the virtualenv.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to install in your machine:

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev python-dev
```